# In Selenium C#, how do enable logging/tracing for each command that gets sent to Selenium?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver

I wish to trace the commands that get sent to `RemoteWebDriver`. For example,

```
public void Test()
{
    RemoteWebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver(); // or ChromeDriver or InternetExplorerDriver
    driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://localhost/");
    driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
    driver.SwitchTo().Frame("contentFrame");
    driver.FindElementById("loginField").SendKeys("username");
    driver.FindElementById("passwordField").SendKeys("password");
    driver.FindElementById("loginButton").Click();
    driver.SwitchTo().DefaultContent();
    driver.SwitchTo().Frame("contentFrame");
    driver.FindElementById("logoutButton").Click();
    driver.Quit();
}
```

would output

```
open            http://localhost/
selectWindow    null
selectFrame     contentFrame
type            loginField           username
type            passwordField        password
click           loginButton
selectWindow    null
selectFrame     contentFrame
click           loginButton
```

[LoggingSelenium](http://loggingselenium.sourceforge.net/) has this for Java, but I am wondering if there is a way to do this in C#.

Comment: I am into Java, so I do not give you the real code, but whenever I need to "log" something, I use standard console output. But I dont know if C# actually offers it

Answer (score 0):

You're under the misconception that there is a one-to-one mapping between Selenium RC commands and Selenium WebDriver commands. There isn't. The WebDriver commands you're using simply may not directly translate to the Selenium RC commands in your sample log, and the project you're referencing is directly related to Selenium RC, not WebDriver.